# org.apache.log4j.jmx is not of production quality? (log4j 1.2)

Tags: java, jmx, spring-jmx

The documentation for log4j JMX beans says "unfortunately managing log4j settings is not production ready" from this link:  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jmx/package-summary.html

No further information.  I'm wondering if all I want to do is monitor the buffer size of the AsyncLogger, will this help me to do so by using something like jconsole or HPDiagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 1.x has been [officially End-of-Life](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces) for over 2.5 years.

They suggest moving to Log4j 2.

Comment: "This is EOL'ed, we should move on"